# Localization problem of my robot in RVİZ environment at first run

Tags: navigation, localization, amcl, ros-noetic

I am doing research for the first positioning for my robot to be done correctly on the map. I have done various researches and applications (such as amcl, ICP) for these and I am still continuing. But I am still having problems solving the problem. I have RGBD camera and Lidar. When the environment is correct, my robot places itself on the map by making forward-backward and rotational movements with laser data in the RVIZ environment.

When I start my robot and in the RVIZ environment, I see the following situations:

- My robot is positioned too far away from the map
- My robot is trying to place itself on the map with lidar in another room (similarity of square/rectangular rooms)
- My robot is trying to place itself on the map in a completely wrong place

Can you help me with these problems (Articles, Applications, etc.)?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: Your issue is known as the Kidnapped Robot Problem. Countless papers by PhD candidates trying and sometimes partially being successful.


Is this a school project?

Comment: It is not a school project. It is a work we developed together with friends.

Comment: I tried to solve it myself using a tensorflow/keras regression algo operating soley on LIDAR data, but found that adding 1-D conv-filters at the inlet improved performance so in the end it wasn't purely a regession model.  There are a couple locations in the house where the errors are large enough that AMCL would not be able to function using the tensoflow prediction. Overall though it worked in most locations/orientations.